# Website URL issue

Tags: redirection, 10

I have an Drupal 10 installation on my Macbook Air. The web root is ~/Sites/drupal10/web. I have a hosts file entry pointing d10.mf.local to localhost and I have an Apache Vhost set up with ServerName = d10.mf.local and DocumentRoot = ~/Sites/drupal10/web.

If I access the site using http://d10.mf.local the front page is displayed but as soon as I try to access any item in the menu the URL has /drupal10/web appended prior to the menu link. So assume I access the site from d10.mf.local and then click on menu Contact Us, instead of the URL being d10.mf.local/contact it becomes d10.mf.local/drupal10/web/contact and gives a page not found error. If I use d10.mf.local/contact the page is correctly displayed.
I have been trying to get to the bottom of this for two days now and am stumped.
If someone can point me in the right direction I would be most appreciative.

Comment: Menu links are cached. Did you clear the cache after changing the web server configuration?

Comment: Exactly - why on earth did I not realise that. Once the caches were cleared everything worked as expected. Many thanks for helping